# How to write the jquery for the following

Tags: jquery

I am new to jquery I want to hide a particular division when a particular element a drop downlist is selected, I also want to increase the size of the adjasent column when the particular is hidden

```js
$(function() {
    $('#d1').change(function() {
        $('#group3').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="group1" id="d1">
    <select class="cls1">
        <option value="">Type</option>
        <option value="QS">1</option>
        <option value="SP">2</option>
        <option value="XL">3</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="div2">
    <div class="group2" , width="50%">
        Division2: Hide when 3 is selected
    </div>

    <div class="group3" , width="50%">
        Hide when 1 or 2 is selected
    </div>
</div>
```

but this hide division group3 every time How can I change it so that it would hide different divisions as per my choice

Comment: So? What did you try our so far?

Comment: @RomeoSierra: How can I change it so that it would hide different divisions as per my choice

Comment: In `$('#group3').hide();` you are trying to access an element using ID Selector+Class value. That is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to give all groups wich u want to hide in JS, a main class name (`groupclass`) like this :

```
<div class="group1" id="d1">
    <select class="cls1">
        <option value="">Type</option>
        <option value="QS">1</option>
        <option value="SP">2</option>
        <option value="XL">3</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="div2">
    <div class="group2 groupclass" , width="50%">
        Division2: Hide when 3 is selected
    </div>
    <div class="group3 groupclass" , width="50%">
        Hide when 1 or 2 is selected
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you need to say in JS, hide all first and show just selected group like this :

```
<script>
    $('#d1 > select').change(function() {
        $('.groupclass').hide();
        $('.group' + $('option:selected', this).text()).show();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```js
$d1 = $('#d1');
$d1.change(function() {
  $("[id^=group]").show();
  var value = $d1.val();
  if (value === "QS" || value === "SP") {
    $('#group3').hide();
  } else if (value === "XL") {
    $('#group2').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="group1">
  <select class="cls1" id="d1">
    <option value="">Type</option>
    <option value="QS">1</option>
    <option value="SP">2</option>
    <option value="XL">3</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="div2">
  <div id="group2" style="width:50%">
    Division2: Hide when 3 is selected
  </div>

  <div id="group3" style="width:50%">
    Hide when 1 or 2 is selected
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following,

```js
$(function() {    

    $('#d1').change(function(){
    
        
       var selected_valule  = $("#d1").val();
        console.log(selected_valule);
        if(selected_valule == "XL" ){
          $('#group3').hide();
            $('#group2').show();
        }else{
          $('#group2').hide();
            $('#group3').show();
        }
      
        
    });

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="group1" >
     <select class="cls1" id="d1">
     <option value="">Type</option>
     <option value="QS">1</option>
     <option value="SP">2</option>
     <option value="XL">3</option>
     </select>
 </div>

<div class="div2">
<div id="group2" style="width:50%">
 Division2: Hide when 3 is selected
</div>


<div id="group3" style="width:50%">
 Hide when 1 or 2 is selected
</div>
</div>
```